# How to alter one Vue TypeScript Component from another?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to get my feet wet with some technologies I've not used before, so I am working off the Visual Studio Vue project template. I have `LoginDialog` and `LoginPanel` components, and I'm trying to get the syntax right for having the 'Login' button in `LoginPanel` set a 'visible' attribute on `LoginDialog`.

```
// Login Dialog .ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class LoginDialogComponent extends Vue {
    visible: boolean = false
}

// Login Panel .ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { LoginDialogComponent } from '../loginDialog/logindialog'

@Component
export default class LoginPanelComponent extends Vue {
    show() {
        LoginDialogComponent.visible = true
    }
}
```

But, in the browser I get an error about the line `import { LoginDialogComponent } from '../loginDialog/logindialog'` saying that

> TS2305: Module '"ClientApp/components/loginDialog/logindialog"' has no exported member 'LoginDialogComponent'

I notice the `LoginDialogComponent` class has the `export` keyword, which would suggest it is exported, and the `visible` member doesn't allow the export keyword. Any idea what I'm mucking up here?

**Edit**

One other thought I had is maybe I need to be wiring these things up in my app.ts file, defined as:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {
        MenuComponent: require('../navmenu/navmenu.vue.html'),
        LoginPanelComponent: require('../loginPanel/loginpanel.vue.html'),
        LoginDialogComponent: require('../loginDialog/logindialog.vue.html')
    }
})
export default class AppComponent extends Vue {
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what it's doing here - do these component listings create instances of the classes they are referencing? If that's the case, I suppose I would have to pass the `Dialog` component to the `Panel` component, or have a reference to the `Dialog` in the `App` component, and pass *that* into the `Panel`?

Comment: Don't use braces in `import { LoginDialogComponent }`, use `import LoginDialogComponent`  instead for default exported modules

Comment: Ah that may be it then! It removes the compile error, but then `Property 'visible' does not exist on type 'typeof LoginDialogComponent` when I try `LoginDialogComponent.visible = true`. Is there a way to access the imported instance?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly braces from your import statement. They cause the error to occur when the imported class is the default exported class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything to do with TypeScript really. It's just letting you know at compile time that what you're importing is not exported. The same exact thing is true in JavaScript.

When you have the following

```
// a.js
export default expression
```

You can import it in the following way

```
import anyValidIdentifer from './a.js';
takesDefaultExportOfA(anyValidIdentifer);
```

Which is a shorthand for

```
import * as anyValidIdentifer from './a.js';
takesDeafultExportOfA(anyValidIdentifer.default);
```

What you may be thrown off by is that the class that is exported is named. That does not mean it is incidentally named export. It is exported as the default. The name of the class is a module scoped local binding for that class, referring to it only only within the module that defines it, not without.

Comment: I don't think the error message is not unclear in what it's saying; I don't know how to resolve though. `export default LoginDialogComponent` doesn't work. In your answer, is there something I can substitute for 'expression' and 'anyValidIdentifier' that will work in my particular situation?